# PHP can't save data in database form sends without validation

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to send data to a database but it doesn't get saved. My Database looks like this:

Database name: logreg

Database Table: users

Users columns:

```
user_id = int, auto_increment, primary
username = varchar 255
email = varchar 255
password = varchar 255
salt = text
```

Database connection:

```
<?php

 $host = 'localhost';
 $username = 'root';
 $password = 'root';
 $dbName = 'logreg';

 $db = @new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbName);

  if(is_string($db->connect_error)){

    die("Keine Verbindung");
  }
```

I also have a Form, it's built like this:

```
 <form action="submit.php" method="post" class="login" onsubmit="return registerForm(this);">
    <h1>Create Account
        <span>Please fill out all fields.</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Username :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Username" />
        <p class="alertMessage"></p>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Adresse" />
        <p class="alertMessage1"></p>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Password :</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password3"  placeholder="Your Passwort">
        <p class="alertMessage2"></p>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Repeat Password :</span>
        <input id="password1" type="password" name="password4" placeholder="repeat Password">
        <p class="alertMessage2"></p>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Countrys :</span><select name="selection">
        <option value="Deutschland">Deutschland</option>
        <option value="Frankreich">Frankreich</option>
        <option value="Spanien">Spanien</option>
        <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
        <option value="Italien">Italien</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Create" />
    </label>

    <a href="anmelden.php">Already Registerd? Click here!</a>
</form>
```

I have validate it with JavaScript and it works fine but PHP validation doesn't work.

```
<?php
include_once 'init.inc.php';

 if($_POST['Create']){

if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['password3'] && $_POST['email']){

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $_POST['password3']));
    $email = "";

    if($_POST['email']){
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    }

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = $username"));

    if($check != '0'){
        die("That username already exists!");
    }

    if(!ctype_alnum($username)){
        die("Username contains special characters");
    }

    if(strlen($username) > 20){

        die("Username is to long ");
    }

    $salt = hash("sha512", rand() . rand(). rand());
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('username', 'password', 'email', 'salt') VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$salt')");
    setcookie("c_user", hash("sha512", $username), time() +24 * 60 * 60, "/");
    setcookie("c_salt", $salt, time() +24 * 60 * 60, "/");
    die("Your Account has been created");
}
 }
 ?>
```

That's for the registration part. Here is the login part.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="login" onsubmit=" return loginForm(this);">
        <h1>Please login with your Credentials
        </h1>
        <label>
            <span>Your Username :</span>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="user1" placeholder="Your Username" />
            <p class="Message"></p>
        </label>

        <label>
            <span>Password :</span>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password5" placeholder="Your Password">
            <p class="Message1"></p>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="Submit" class="button" value="Login"/>
        </label>
    <a href="registrieren.php">Not a Member? Click here!</a>
    </form>
```

The PHP part for the login:

```
<?php

include_once 'init.inc.php';

 if($_POST['Login']){

if($_POST['user1'] && $_POST['password5']){

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user1']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $_POST['password5']));
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username'='$username'"));

    if($user == '0'){
        die("That username doesn't exist!");
    }

    if($user['password5'] != $password){
        die("Incorrect password");
    }

    $salt = hash("sha512", rand() . rand() . rand());
    setcookie("c_user", hash("sha512", $username), time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
setcookie("c_salt", $salt, time() + 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
    $userID = $user['user_id'];
    mysqli_query("UPDATE 'users' SET 'salt' = '$salt' WHERE 'user_id' = '$userID' ");
    die("You are now logged in as $username");

}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: When you say that the PHP validating doesn't work. What is the error/behaviour your get ?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($query` is incorrect, you need the connection in there.

Comment: `Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result parameter.` So you will never get `0` with `if($check != '0')`. Try the number rows function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['Create']){
```

This is wrong from what I can see from your form.
It should be:

```
if($_POST['submit']){
```

The reason for this is following code:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Create" />
```

POST uses the name value, which is submit in this case.

Same goes for the login part.

```
<input type="Submit" class="button" value="Login"/>
```

This has no name value.
Change it to:

```
<input type="Submit" name="Login" class="button" value="Login"/>
```

Then you can start working on getting some of your functions working correctly. But that should be easier to figure out. If not, I'll be glad to know and help :).

Comment: I know, but this should improve some of the biggest ones. The others should be easier to figure out once he gets the actual submit part working :).

Comment: i changed now the part that you told me thanks :) but it still just sends the form without any validation and i don't get a error from PHP

Comment: If you get any new errors, let us know and we'll try our best to help you!

Comment: i can't get it  to work to send the data to the database to save it in there :(

Comment: Add this to your php : error_reporting(-1);
This will show you the errors you have when trying to submit. Then give us the errors :).

Comment: i'm getting 5 warnings,  3 warnings saying mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given.   1 warning saying mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, given 1.  and 1 warning saying mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() error: mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user1']);
Should change that to mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user1']); -> $conn being your connection. Same for the query. Change it to: $user = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username'='$username'")); . As for your mysqli_fetch_array(), I don't know why you use it. Remove it and make the changes I recommended :)

Comment: i changed it and now i'm getting the message "Your Account has been created" which i defined under the $salt. But nothing is saved in the Database... i don't know why. Also no errors anymore. Any idea why it's not been saved in the database?

Comment: Just for troubleshooting, remove the following lines: $salt = hash("sha512", rand() . rand(). rand());
setcookie("c_user", hash("sha512", $username), time() +24 * 60 * 60, "/");
    setcookie("c_salt", $salt, time() +24 * 60 * 60, "/");
And instead of die("Your Account has been created");, change it to echo "Your account has been created"; Later on we will add the code back, but this way we can check if that is the reason it's not working :)

Comment: i changed everything you told me :) when i submit the form i get the message "Your account has been created" but still no data saved in database :/

Comment: Add this above your insert query where $salt used to be. $salt = 'text'; Your query needs the value $salt to execute. Else, you have to remove that from your query and make sure your column salt accepts NULL values.

Comment: i changed that now :) but still no data in database

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'm going to reproduce everything on my database and try to get it working :)

Comment: $password = mysqli_real_escape_string(hash("sha512", $_POST['password3'])); Change to $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password3']);

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been able to find it. I am more fluent in pdo though. I hope someone else can help.

Comment: alright, thanks anyway for your time and your help :)

Comment: If you want, I can try and make it work with pdo. But I don't know how soon I can get to work on it

Comment: we don't use pdo in school so i'm not allowed to use it in my project unfortunately :(